# CouchDB: synchronize between slave databases

Tags: synchronization, couchdb, master-slave

**Scenario:** 
 1 big CouchDB database (master) and several read-only databases (slaves) that continuously replicate from master.

Is it possible to configure additional replications between slaves?
Is it possible to only trigger slave-to-slave replication, when master is not reachable or connection speed is to slow?

Comment: Well there is of course BigCouch. http://bigcouch.cloudant.com/ Problem is it's master/master. But as long as you never explicitly write to all but one node, it can "feel" like master/slave. =) The replication is very fast from my usage with a few gigs of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replicate without fear in all directions. Couchdb allows multi-master replication and this is one of the things that makes it different from most other DBs. Just take int account that:

- If you create circular replications or very complicated paths, sometimes it becomes difficult to know where data is coming from.
- You'll have to supervise replication with your own tools. If you want to enable replications between some databases based on network conditions, you'll have to write your own script for that but this is definitely feasible.